# WMS or WFS for selecting features and show attributes?

Tags: openlayers-2, wms, wfs, mapserver

I am beginner in MapServer and Openlayers.

I want to be able to select features and show their attributes by user click. I don't need to edit any feature.

I know this is possible with WFS, but don't know about WMS.

is this possible with WMS?

What are your suggestions?

Comment: It is possible. Read about GetFeatureInfo from http://mapserver.org/ogc/wms_server.html. Configuring is a little bit tricky with Mapserver but you should be able to make is by reading the document. It would be better to learn WMS and WFS with anything else than OpenLayers, like browser or QGIS.

Comment: thank you. i want to learn all of them and start learning of all. but now  i have a project and should concentrate on necessary skills.

now, what's your suggestion between WMS and WFS for my needs?
what is faster?

Comment: I don't know. Speed error is not meaningful, if system has been set up right both are fast. This is GetFeatureInfo http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wms?bbox=-100.00,35.00,-99.99,35.01&styles=&format=jpeg&request=GetFeatureInfo&layers=topp:states&query_layers=topp:states&width=2&height=2&x=1&y=1 and this is GetFeature http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wfs?service=wfs&version=1.0.0&request=getfeature&typename=topp:states&maxfeatures=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a feature of the Web Map Service (WMS) interface standard through the use of a GetFeatureInfo request.  In your web server software, you need to make the layer queryable.